# Protected Routes and Nested Routes are not working together in react routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

My nested privateRoute is not working. 
When I changed the nested routes in normal routing like `/route` everything works fine but as I switch to nested routes like `/route/nested-route` PrivateRoute component loses its functionality.

---

This is the main routing in my app component.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login">
          <ProvideAuth>
            <Login />
          </ProvideAuth>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <SignUpProvider>
            <SignUp />
          </SignUpProvider>
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={UserHome} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={UserProfile} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

PrivateRoute Component works fine in this main routing.

---

This is code of nested and protected route.

```js
const UserHome = () => {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header />
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/feed`} component={Feed} />
          <PrivateRoute path={`${url}/search`} />
          <PrivateRoute path={`${url}/addUser`} />
          <PrivateRoute path={`${url}/notification`} />
          <PrivateRoute path={`${url}/profile`} component={UserProfile} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
      <BottomNavbar />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

PrivateRoute is not working in this nested routing. The redirect route is not firing when the user logs out.

---

Code for PrivateRoute Component.

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const cookie = document.cookie;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => {
        return cookie ? children : <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: have you tried to use useEffect and useState hooks? when use logs in and out, user credentials will change but if your component lifecycles does not depend on them, React will not re-render them. cokies are static meaning you need to subscribe to changes on them if you want reactions in your components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the `cookie` value is computed once, initially, when the `PrivateRoute` component is mounted and rendered. It's a stale value from the enclosure.

Move the `cookie` *into* the returned render function so it's accessed when the path is matched.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={() => document.cookie ? children : <Redirect to="/login" />}
  />
);
```

Comment: Your point is correct. However, your PrivateRoute is also causing the same issue. I think the component is being re-rendered when I log out and that is causing the issue.

Comment: @MukulSharma Ok, let me standup a codesandbox and do some testing. TBH I think it may be because something ***isn't*** rerendered. Can you share your auth code, how a user logs in and out?

Comment: @MukulSharma Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-kilby-4tywv?file=/src/App.js:142-218). I've mocked setting/clearing of a "cookie" but the private route logic works. That being said, it's probably very easy to mess up setting and deleting actual cookies, so if you could share more of your code so we have better context that would be helpful.